# htaccess Deny from all not working

Tags: .htaccess

Trying to deny access to a specific subfolder on a site.
I put an htaccess file in the subfolder with the following text:

```
    Deny from all
```

But it has no effect. I also tried:

```
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
```

Wondering if there's some configuration I have to change?
I use GoDaddy for hosting.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Which version of apache are you using?

Comment: Not sure... How exactly would I go about finding that out?